# Android.Gradle. Separate data from code

Tags: android, gradle

In my app/build.gradle I have about 30 defined constants.
Something like this:

```
 def MY_CONST1 = "http://..."
 def MY_CONST2 = "dB_name"
 ...
 def MY_CONST30 = "some value"
```

As result data (constants) and code that process this data is mixed. I think this is not good. So I want to separate them. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can define these data in `local.properies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use different gradle files to separate them:

`constants.gradle`:

```
ext {
      MY_CONST1 = "http://..."
      MY_CONST2 = "dB_name"
      ...
      MY_CONST30 = "some value"
}
```

In your `app/build.gradle`:

```
...
...
apply from: 'constants.gradle'
```

Also you could put all your custom gradle files in a folder called `gradlescript` (or as you want). In this case in your `app/build.gradle` use:

```
apply from: 'gradlescript/constants.gradle'
```

Comment: It's not work: I get error: Error:(2, 0) Could not get unknown property 'MY_CONST1' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:myproject\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: @user8542613 remove DEF since it is valid only for a local variable. Check the updated answer